# Get the first parameter of a command stored in the form of a String

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I'm trying to extract the first parameter from the String which I'll get from a TextBox.

The first parameter could be or could not be enclosed in double quotes.

In C, I would check if the first character is double quotes until I would a non-white space character, if that character is a double quote, then extract the string until you encounter the same first character into a buffer, else extract the first word into the buffer (until you encounter a white-space).

In VB.net this would look overwhelmingly complex if implemented in VB.Net.

Is there any specific library function to achieve it with sanity?

Basically this,

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs(0)
```

but assuming the command has been inputted in a TextBox can I now want to parse it.

Comment: What has the title got to do with the question? Is it just a `String` or is it a command with parameters? Please provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem and a title that summarises the actual problem. Any ambiguity means that we have to guess and that means that we can guess wrong.

Comment: Is it fine now @jmcilhinney?

Comment: There's no specific method call to do that but to say that writing some manual parsing code would be overwhelmingly complex in VB is an overwhelming exaggeration.

Comment: Please provide an solution

Comment: Where's your attempt to do so? What issue(s) did you have when doing so? It's not for us to write your code for you. We are here to help with issues you encounter along the way. You've already demonstrated that you know what the code has to do so you need to attempt to write code to do it. If you encounter an actual issue, we can help you overcome it. That said, the .NET `String` class provides `Split`, Substring`, `StartsWith` and `IndexOf` methods, so why not make use of some or all of those? String manipulation in .NET is easy. Give it a go.

Comment: Anyways, I'm sorry to waste your time

Comment: SO is a place to get help with problems you have encountered while making an attempt to implement something. If you haven't made an attempt then you haven't encountered any issues. It's not a place to get people to write your code for you so that you don't have to try. If you're willing to make an attempt but can't get it to work then I'll be the first to help you fix it. If you won't even try then your question will likely be closed. Instead of complaining, maybe spend your time trying to write the code. If you won;t try, why should we?

Comment: For the record, I've written and tested two solutions in the last half hour. Each one was encapsulated in a function and they were 24 and 21 lines each in total. As I said, not overwhelmingly complex. Until I see an attempt though, I won't be helping further, because that's not what SO is for.

Comment: Please don't take my words in that way...Actually as an x86 programmer, I think OOP should highly declarative , so I assumed that it could have had an function already for it...I had already solved the problem long ago by trimming the string checking the first char, returning the first word if it isn't a double quote or scanning the string until another double quote is found...I'm sorry if my words took you so long...Even my attitude becomes like yours at times ;)

Comment: You could use [RegEx as shown in this posting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/10828) to parse the string into an array of quoted/unquoted strings. Then just process that array applying your additional constraints.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim t as string= YourTextBox.Text
dim substring() as string =  t.split(" ")
replace(substring(0),char(1))
```

Untest so you might have to make minor adjustments.

Comment: My one-liner `replace(YourTextBox.Text.split(" ")(0),char(1))`

Comment: But what is char(1)? Note: The above code doesn't work

Comment: This is of no use because it ignores spaces inside quoted values.

Comment: Please delete this answer. It doesn't solve the problem.